# Como bloquear las fechas en un DateRangePicker con datos de un array

Tags: php, javascript, bootstrap, daterangepicker

Tengo un daterangepicker de bootstrap en el cual me gustaría hacer una serie de condiciones para que según las fechas que hay en la base de datos se bloqueen y cambien de color. Mi problema es que no sé muy bien cómo decirle al DateRangePicker que me coja las fechas del array que recibo del php sin que desaparezca de la web y quede un recuadro blanco.

EDITO: mi json que recibo en la vista, no lo interpreta correctamente el datepicker

Mi daterangepicker es este:

```
 <script>
  // Aqui recibimos el json de PHP
  var daysData = <?= $data) ?>;
  $( function() {
    $( 'input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({

         isInvalidDate: function(date) { 
          var year = date.year();
          var month = date.month() + 1;
          var day = date.date();
          var valid = false; // default css class

          if(typeof daysData[year] != 'undefined'){
              if(typeof daysData[year][month] != 'undefined'){

                  if(typeof daysData[year][month][day] != 'undefined'){
                   console.log(year, month, day,  daysData[year][month][day]);
                      dayData = daysData[year][month][day]; 
                      //if (dayData['news'] == true){
                        valid = true;
                      //}
                  }
              }
          }
          return valid;
        },

      isCustomDate: function(date) { 
        var year = date.year();
        var month = date.month() + 1;
        var day = date.date();

        var daySettings = 'day_green'; // default css class
        if(typeof daysData[year] != 'undefined'){
            if(typeof daysData[year][month] != 'undefined'){

                if(typeof daysData[year][month][day] != 'undefined'){
                 console.log(year, month, day,  daysData[year][month][day]);
                    dayData = daysData[year][month][day]; 
                    //if (dayData['news'] == true){
                      daySettings = 'day_red';
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
        return daySettings;
    },               
});
</script>
```

La variable $data que recibo de php tiene el siguiente json ( ya lo transforme en el controlador)

```
[{
    "area_id": null,
    "title": "Comida",
    "start": "2018-08-13 00:00:00"
}, {
    "area_id": null,
    "title": "Conferencia",
    "start": "2018-08-19 00:00:00"
}, {
    "area_id": null,
    "title": "Meeting",
    "start": "2018-08-27 00:00:00"
}, {
    "area_id": null,
    "title": "Cumplea\u00f1os",
    "start": "2018-08-05 00:00:00"
}, {
    "area_id": null,
    "title": "Fecha disponible",
    "start": "2018-08-14 00:00:00"
}, {
    "area_id": null,
    "title": "Fechas No Disponibles",
    "start": "2018-07-30 00:00:00"
}, {
    "area_id": null,
    "title": "Consultar Fecha",
    "start": "2018-08-06 00:00:00"
}, {
    "area_id": 1,
    "title": "vacacion",
    "start": "2018-08-17 00:00:00"
}, {
    "area_id": 1,
    "title": "vacacion",
    "start": "2018-08-17 00:00:00"
}, {
    "area_id": 1,
    "title": "vacacion",
    "start": "2018-08-17 00:00:00"
}, {
    "area_id": 1,
    "title": "vacacion",
    "start": "2018-08-17 00:00:00"
}, {
    "area_id": 1,
    "title": "vacacion",
    "start": "2018-08-17 00:00:00"
}, {
    "area_id": 1,
    "title": "vacacion",
    "start": "2018-08-17 00:00:00"
}, {
    "area_id": 1,
    "title": "vacacion",
    "start": "2018-08-17 00:00:00"
}, {
    "area_id": 1,
    "title": "vacacion",
    "start": "2018-08-17 00:00:00"
}, {
    "area_id": 1,
    "title": "vacacion",
    "start": "2018-08-17 00:00:00"
}, {
    "area_id": 1,
    "title": "vacacion",
    "start": "2018-08-17 00:00:00"
}, {
    "area_id": 1,
    "title": "vacacion",
    "start": "2018-08-17 00:00:00"
}, {
    "area_id": 1,
    "title": "vacacion",
    "start": "2018-08-17 00:00:00"
}, {
    "area_id": 1,
    "title": "vacacion",
    "start": "2018-08-17 00:00:00"
}, {
    "area_id": 1,
    "title": "vacacion",
    "start": "2018-08-17 00:00:00"
}, {
    "area_id": 1,
    "title": "vacacion",
    "start": "2018-08-17 00:00:00"
}]
```

¿Cómo puedo utilizar este json para tener todas las fechas que vengan de bd como que están ocupadas, y marcarlas con otro color en el DateRangePicker? Estaba pensando en quitarle datos al array en php y pasarle solo la fecha, pero quiero conservar el area_id para hacer unas condiciones y que ponga distintos colores.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para date range picker tienes dos funciones:

- **isInvalidDate**. esta funcion se ejecuta antes de crear el calendario y marcara la celda del dia como valida o invalida dependiendo de su retorno:
  ejemplo:

  ```
  $('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
    isInvalidDate: function (date) {
      var r = false;
      if (date == LoQueSea) r = true;
      return r;
    }
  });
  ```

  Si devuelves true: invalida, false: valida. (valida o invalida, si es seleccionable)
- **isCustomDate**. esta función se ejecuta antes de crear el calendario y le dará clases personalizadas a las celdas, siendo cada celda individual por el día. Ejemplo:

  ```
  $('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
    isCustomDate: function (date) {
      var clase = ''; //no queremos ninguna clase
      if (date == LoQueSea) clase = 'warning';
      return date ;
    }
  });
  ```

  Entonces, las celdas que queramos tendran la clase warning

---

**JSON**

Para no hacer un bucle cada vez que se llama a una de estas funciones, lo mejor es construir el JSON una vez lo hemos recibido.

Como lo que nos importa es el campo *start*, este lo ponemos como key de cada valor:

```
var newA = [];
for( j of daysData){
  let d = moment(j["start"]).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
  newA[d] = j;
}
```

Donde `newA` un nuevo json construido.

Para verlo mas grafico:

```
[
   "05/08/2018":{
      area_id:null,
      title:"Cumpleaños",
      start:"2018-08-05 00:00:00"
   },
   ​
"06/08/2018":{
      area_id:null,
      title:"Consultar Fecha",
      start:"2018-08-06 00:00:00"
   },
...]
```

---

A partir de aquí, si utilizamos tu código y en base a lo que ya tienes:

```
$('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({

    isInvalidDate: function(date) { 
      var valid = false; 
      let d =  date.format("DD/MM/YYYY"); // <-- aqui construimos la key del array
      if(typeof newA[d] != 'undefined'){
        dayData = newA[d]
        valid = true;
      }
      return valid;
    },
   isCustomDate: function(date) { 
      var daySettings = 'day_green';
      let d =  date.format("DD/MM/YYYY"); // <-- aqui construimos la key del array
      if(typeof newA[d] != 'undefined'){
        dayData = newA[d]
        daySettings = 'day_red';
      }
      return daySettings;
    },
});
```

> Algunas aclaraciones
>
> - He quitado algo de código para limpiar la respuesta, y fuera entendible.
> - Para que te funcione la clase css en las fechas invalidas (mas que nada el background-color), has de hacerlo `!important`
>
> Y luego, aunque creo que no tiene que ver con la respuesta, esta bien
>   que sepas que las fechas, DateRange picker, utiliza [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/),
>   por eso, para sacar el formato de la fecha, he utilizado las propias
>   funciones del momentjs

---

Tienes el ejemplo [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/658435/)

Comment: En cuanto tenga tiempo, lo pruebo, he simplificado el array porque me parecio mejor no llevar datos que no necesito. Edito. Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta, no pensé que fuera tan complejo. Saludos.

Comment: disculpa las molestias, voy a editar el post para que veas los cambios que hice, he comprobado la pagina que me compartiste y veo que funciona correctamente el metodo pero no esta cojiendo las fechas como deberia, de hecho marca en rojo los dias que trae digamos en la cabecera del json, y en mi pagina, el datepicker si que aparece pero debe ser que no esta entendiendo el json que le paso. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Claro, me imaginado que el orden del json coincidiria con el campo start del json. SI puedes pasa toda la estructura del json y miramos

Comment: Editado, agradezco tu ayuda cuando puedas, me parece muy interesante esto de tratar los datos, siempre me ha sido bastante confuso.

Comment: le echo un ojo!

Comment: HE editado la respuesta con el nuevo JSON, y el ejemplo tambien

Comment: Funciona!!!! me tacha las fechas que estan ocupadas, muchas gracias, ahora tengo que ver el css para que coja el color, eres un crack! Menudo dolor de cabeza me has quitado de encima

Comment: YEah, me alegro! si te fijas en lo del color tienes que poner `background-color: red !important`. Si no le pones *!important* no te va a coger tu css

Comment: Esta hecho! Ahora me surge una duda, si quisiera pintar en rojo y bloquear, todas las fechas comprendidas entre 2? Me explico, si quisiera coger start y end, para bloquear el intervalo entre esas 2 fecha, seria mejor tratar todas las fechas intermedias como fechas independientes, o existe algun metodo para que el datepicker interprete el intervalo? ( Solo de escribirlo ya me estoy haciendo un lio). He conseguido tratarlas todas por separado, metiendo fechas como si no hubiera mañana en el array. Muchas gracias de verdad, ya voy entendiendo un poco mejor js

Comment: pues mira, ya que tienes momentjs, tienes [moment.isBetween](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) `date.isBetween(start, end);` parece sencillo, pero si tienes alguna duda, te recomiendo que abras una nueva pregunta

Comment: Perfecto, voy a intentarlo, así añado el end tambien al array, muchas gracias por todo!

Comment: Buenas tardes @Txema, siento volver a darte la vara, pero he leido la documentacion que me pasaste y he estado viendo ejemplos y maneras de hacerlo, pero el metodo isBetween() en la propia documentación me indica que no me sirve para lo que intento hacer yo. He intentado agregar el metodo isBetween, e incluso he probado con otro plugin de moment.js que se llama range, pero no he conseguido hacer que funcione, he creado un post, por si puedes hecharme algo de luz al agujero. Muchas gracias anticipadas y un saludo!!

Comment: Hola david, Acabao de ver tu otra pregunta, te la estoy respondiendo. Dejame 5min que acabe la respuesta y te la miras :)

Comment: Cuando tu puedas compañero, muchas gracias :D